How to run For Each activity if a value is true on ADF?
I have a Lookup activity where I check whether a Kusto (ADX) value is true or false and then I can run my next Lookup activity and finally my For Each activity that is based on the second Lookup values.
The thing is, I only want to run the second Lookup and For Each if Condition is true, but ADF doesn't allow For Each to be inside of If Activity, and I already have plenty of pipelines that is calling a child pipeline (I hate this kind of solution because it gets so ugly and somehow looks that it's very duplicated for the same solution).
Is there a way to check this before running the For Each? I tried Validation activity but looks like it doesn't accept values from a Lookup, only from a Dataset.
This is my current logic:

But in this case it's not working because For Each will always run regardless of if condition is true or false.

You can use Do-if-skip-else-block error handling approach as a workaround for this scenario.
First create an integer variable in the pipeline variable section. Now, take a set variable and give your if activity condition in that.
@if(<Your if activity expression>,1,'1')


Here, I have used True and False as the if activity expression results. This set variable activity acts as an if activity and its success and failure will act as if and else scenarios.
Add your True activities on the success of this set variable activity and False activities on the failure of it. After the last activity of True activities, add a sample set variable activity upon the skipping of the last activity.
You can check this summary table of error handling approaches to understand this approach.
Here, if your if expression is true, the above expression assigns an integer value 1 to the integer variable var1 and activity succeeds. Then your True activities will be executed along with your For-Each.

If the expression results False, then the above expression assigns a string value '1' to the integer variable which results the activity failure. Then your False activities will be executed.

In this approach to stop the failure of the pipeline like Do-if-else block, extra set variable activity was used upon the skipping of the last True activity. This succeeds the pipeline on the failure of the fake if activity like above.
